# "ConvergenceWarning: Liblinear failed to converge, increase the number of iterations." Error when training SVM with MNIST data

Tags: scikit-learn, svm, mnist

i've encountered this

```
warnings.warn("Liblinear failed to converge, increase
```

when training LinearSVC, below is my code:

```py
from sklearn import datasets        
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC                               
import numpy as np                                          
from collections import Counter
import cv2
import joblib


# Download the dataset
dataset = datasets.fetch_openml('mnist_784', version=1) 

# Extract the features and labels
features = np.array(dataset.data, 'int16') 
labels = np.array(dataset.target, 'int')

print(np.shape(features))
print(np.shape(labels))

# Create an linear SVM object
clf = LinearSVC()

# Perform the training
clf.fit(features, labels)

# Save the classifier
joblib.dump(clf, "raw_digits_cls.pkl", compress=3)
```

I found some other posts but it still has not solved my problem. `Normalize the data with features = features/255.0` did not work.
Any help will be much appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: Use `LinearSVC(dual=False)`. The default is to solve the dual problem, which is not recommended when n_samples > n_features, which is the case for you. This recommendation is from [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.html) of LinearSVC of scikit-learn.

But beware that you don't have much to monitor the performance of the model since you are using all of the data to train i.e. you don't seem to do train/test split(s).

Comment: Thanks @MustafaAydın for comment. it did the trick although the training time increased, I actually tend to use all of the data to train. because i will use it for recognition the digit from my own images.

Comment: The error is suggesting to increase `max_iter` parameter (`max_iter`=1000 by default) within `LinearSVC()` instantiation. For instance, `clf = LinearSVC(max_iter=5000)`.